# PHP PDO Batch Update - Exists?

Tags: java, php, jdbc, pdo

I am looking similar way to jdbc driver in Java, to perform a batch of updates in PHP.

In jdbc there is an API of `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()`, which executes the whole statements in one round trip to the DB.

Does PHP PDO has similar API, and if not, does starting transaction, doing the updates and then commit will do the same effect of executing all updates in one round trip to the DB or each update will round trip to the DB and immediately executing the statement (although not visible to others, since it is in transaction)?

Answer (score 0):

PHP PDO doesn't have batch execution of queries.

Running many inserts and updates in a transaction usually improves greatly the execution speed. If you're making batch jobs on a database you should run queries in bulks within a transaction.

Comment: This DB is used for OLTP and for this speciffic task which I want to do in a batch. Making it in a transaction will result for locking the rows updated, which in my case is pretty the whole table. So I need actually someway to execute the batch without a transaction.

Comment: The link to the nextRowset documentation is not relevant to this question. nextRowset is for retrieving multiple rowsets produced by a single stored procedure call, not for the batch execution of update queries.

Comment: Sorry, I came back looking at this question after ages... and read it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like "batch update" in Mysql. There are SQL queries only.
As long as you can do your updates in one query, your updates will be done in one round-trip. Otherwise there would be many. No matter what API being used.

Speaking of single SQL queries, there are 2 possible ways

1. CASE statement in WHERE
2. A neat trick with INSERT(!) query with ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statement. Which will actually update your data.

Comment: What do you mean by CASE statement in WHERE? I want to update for each row different value for some field.